# How to put a toolbar directly beneath a tabpanel

Tags: sencha-touch

Here is my current code (with heights/widths omitted):

```
myapp.cards.addvehicle = new Ext.TabPanel({
    scroll: 'vertical',
    id: "home2",
    layout:{
        type:"vbox",
    },
    dockedItems: [{ 
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top'
    }]
});
```

but it places the toolbar above the tabpanel. Adding a toolbar in the items part of the configuration object doesn't produce the desired result either. Has anyone been able to accomplish this and if so, how?

Note: I believe that by default in extjs4 the toolbar appear below the tabbar when docked at the top, although I can't confirm this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **bottom** on the docked toolbar item:

```
myapp.cards.addvehicle = new Ext.TabPanel({
    scroll: 'vertical',
    id: "home2",
    layout:{
        type:"vbox",
    },
    dockedItems: [{ 
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: '**bottom**'
    }]
});
```